# Using XSLT in order to return an empty valid JSON object

Tags: xml, json, xslt

We're consuming a web service which returns an XML, and we're using XSLT in order to sort the date and send only part of it into a mobile client. The data returned to the client is JSON parsed.
On a given parameter, the service returns an empty XML - as shown at the end of the question.

What we want to do in this case is to figure out how to return an empty valid JSON object (i.e., []) to the client. Currently we cannot change anything in the web service itself. Any idea would be most helpful.

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Events">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="boneId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="nsId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="objId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="fileName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ArieId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="EventPlaceName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="City" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PlaceFileName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PlaceBoneId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PlaceNsId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PlaceObjId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="TourName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="TimeStart" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="TimeEnd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Genre" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Genre_Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" />
</DataSet>
```

The XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="Events">
        {
            'Items': [
                <xsl:for-each select="//Events">                                
                    {

                        'Name':             '<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>',
                        'Date':             '<xsl:value-of select="Date"/>',
                        'PlaceName':        '<xsl:value-of select="EventPlaceName"/>',
                        'boneId':           '<xsl:value-of select="boneId"/>',
                        'objId':            '<xsl:value-of select="objId"/>',
                        'PlaceNsId':        '<xsl:value-of select="PlaceNsId"/>',
                        'PlaceObjId':       '<xsl:value-of select="PlaceObjId"/>',
                        'StartPoint':       '<xsl:value-of select="StartPoint"/>',
                        'Description':      '<xsl:value-of select="Description"/>',
                        'Telephone':        '<xsl:value-of select="Telephone"/>'
                    },
                </xsl:for-each>
            ]       
        }
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A "regular" XML response from the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Events">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="boneId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="nsId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="objId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="fileName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ArieId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="EventPlaceName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="City" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PlaceFileName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PlaceBoneId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PlaceNsId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PlaceObjId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="TourName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="TimeStart" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="TimeEnd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Genre" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Genre_Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
      <Events diffgr:id="Events1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <boneId>1855</boneId>
        <nsId>305</nsId>
        <objId>28</objId>
        <fileName>tours_item_show.aspx</fileName>
        <ArieId>1</ArieId>
        <EventPlaceName>Place name</EventPlaceName>
        <City>392</City>
        <PlaceFileName>show_item_place.aspx</PlaceFileName>
        <PlaceBoneId>1563</PlaceBoneId>
        <PlaceNsId>201</PlaceNsId>
        <PlaceObjId>2574</PlaceObjId>
        <TourName>Tour name</TourName>
        <Genre>18</Genre>
        <Genre_Name>Group tours</Genre_Name>
      </Events>
    </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Comment: "*On a given parameter, the service returns an empty XML - as shown at the end of the question.*" I don't see where you show that. And its very important that you do, because there is no such thing as an empty XML. If must have at least a root element - otherwise it's not XML at all.

Comment: BTW, I think you have mistakenly posted the XSD instead of an example of an actual XML response. So please edit our question and provide **two** examples of the XML input: a "regular" one, and an "empty" one.

Comment: The XML I've attached is the actual response returning from the service. I have added a "regular" to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood the question, but isn't this simply a matter of adding the template rule

```
<xsl:template match="diffgr:diffgram">[]</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think that you have understood the question. However the rule above does not do the trick. The idea is to have a template rule for a case with data (already done) and a case without data, and to be able to use the same XSLT for both cases. The rule you suggested fails in both cases, providing the following error: 'Namespace prefix 'diffgr' is undeclared.'

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you knew enough XSLT to know that if you use a namespace prefix in a match pattern, you have to declare it.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you feed XML to that stylesheet containing more than one Event node, you will realize that you don't want a for-each in there.

But as far as the main question is concerned -- how empty are we talking about?  I mean, a zero-length file isn't valid XML.  But, if you are getting a NewDataSet with no Event nodes in it, you should create the enclosing object at that level, and you would automatically get an empty object if there are no Events.  Something along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
    {
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    }
<xsl:template>
```

**UPDATE:**

After seeing the additional post ("regular" XML), I see what an ugly web service you are dealing with.  Really?  They embed the schema in every response, even if that response gives you no data?  Ugh.

Anyway, a variation on what I had suggested before should work.  It seems like the one thing you are assured of receiving is the diffgram node.  So make that the one that creates the enclosing JSON object.  I suggest you add an xslns:diffgr declaration in your XSL -- local-name() feels like cheating to me.

So, you would be doing something along the lines of this:

```
<xsl:template match="diffgr:diffgram">
    {
    <xsl:apply-templates select="NewDataSet/Events"/>
    }
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hesitate how exactly to answer this, because your stylesheet does not return a valid JSON document even when the response contains data. So I suggest you take a look at the following and, if necessary, make the required adjustments.

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
{<xsl:apply-templates select="*/NewDataSet"/>}
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
"Items":[<xsl:apply-templates select="Events"/>]
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Events">
    {
        "Name":             "<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>",
        "Date":             "<xsl:value-of select="Date"/>",
        "PlaceName":        "<xsl:value-of select="EventPlaceName"/>",
        "boneId":           "<xsl:value-of select="boneId"/>",
        "objId":            "<xsl:value-of select="objId"/>",
        "PlaceNsId":        "<xsl:value-of select="PlaceNsId"/>",
        "PlaceObjId":       "<xsl:value-of select="PlaceObjId"/>",
        "StartPoint":       "<xsl:value-of select="StartPoint"/>",
        "Description":      "<xsl:value-of select="Description"/>",
        "Telephone":        "<xsl:value-of select="Telephone"/>"
    }
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your **second input XML example**, will return:

```
{
"Items":[
    {
        "Name":             "Name",
        "Date":             "",
        "PlaceName":        "Place name",
        "boneId":           "1855",
        "objId":            "28",
        "PlaceNsId":        "201",
        "PlaceObjId":       "2574",
        "StartPoint":       "",
        "Description":      "",
        "Telephone":        ""
    }
]
}
```

which is not exactly the same thing your stylesheet produces - but it does pass the validation here:http://jsonlint.com/

The **same** stylesheet, when applied to your **first input XML example**, will return:

```
{}
```

Note: I believe using `<xsl:text>` to output literal text offers a much better control of whitespace.